# Give html value to a link_to and then get the value from the controller in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have 3 links in my main view in my rails app and I want to show different data in the index view depending on the link the user clicks:

```
<%= link_to 'Explorar', url: index_page_url, :name => 'cunas'%>
<%= link_to 'Explorar', url: index_page_url, :name => 'accesorios'%>
<%= link_to 'Explorar', url: index_page_url, :name => 'ropa'%>
```

So that in the controller I can do something like this:

```
def index
    if linkname == "cunas" then 
        @product = Product.where(:type == 'cunas')
    elsif linkname == "accesorios" then
        @product = Product.where(:type == 'accesorios')
    elsif linkname == "ropa" then
        @product = Product.where(:type == 'ropa')
    end
end
```

Is there a `onClick` function or `.click` that i can use in the rails controller?

Also is `Product.where(:type == 'cunas')` enough to save all the products that have `type == cunas` in `@product`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a couple of things.  first the link_to

try this:

```
link_to 'Explorar', {url: index_page_url(type: :ropa)}, :name => 'ropa'
link_to 'Explorar', {url: index_page_url(type: :accesorios), :name => 'accesorios'
link_to 'Explorar', {url: index_page_url(type: :ropa)}, :name => 'ropa'
```

(don't forget your erb tags which I omitted here)

then in your controller

```
def index
  type = params[:type]
  Product.where(type: type)
end
```

the signature for link_to is as follows:

```
link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
```

So you want to pass the type as a parameter to the controller and fetch the value back out of the params.  Depending on your controller code you may also need to add type to your strong parameters.